# How to interpret “si […] et que […]” followed by a main clause?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, conditions

Sometimes I find sentences like the following:

> **Si** vous êtes pressé **et  que** vous n'avez pas envie de prendre les
>   transports en commun, vous pouvez toujours prendre un taxi.

Why is it *si […] et que […]* + main clause? My understanding is that it is the same as *si […] et si […]*. Is it correct?

Any other cases where the conjunction appears the second time as *que*? Is it more formal this way or quite the contrary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost all [subordinate conjunctions](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjonction_de_subordination) in French end in *-que* (either as a word ending, e.g. *lorsque*, *quoique*, or as a separate word, e.g. *bien que*, *tant que*). When they are repeated, only the *que* part is repeated.

> **Lorsqu'**il va venir et **qu'**il va voir ce qui s'est passé, il ne va pas être content.

There are a few conjunctions that do not end in *-que*, but we still use *que* when repeating them.

> **Quand** il va venir et **qu'**il va voir ce qui s'est passé, il ne va pas être content.
>   **Si** vous êtes pressé et **que** vous n'avez pas envie de prendre les transports en commun, vous pouvez toujours prendre un taxi.

It is sometimes possible to use *si* the second time. This tends to put some emphasis on the necessity of the second condition being true. Some purists may frown on this construction.

> **Si** vous êtes pressé et **si** vous n'avez pas envie de prendre les transports en commun, vous pouvez toujours prendre un taxi.
>   *If you're in a hurry, and if you really don't want to take public transport, you could take a taxi.*

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! :) But what's the register in this case? Can I use it also in spoken French?

Comment: @RickyRobinson Spoken French tends to avoid such long constructions. When they're used there's definitely more of a trend to repeat *si* because by the time the second part comes the beginning of the sentence is already fading in the listener's mind. I wouldn't repeat *quand*, but I might repeat *si*.

Answer (score 2):

I see two main reason to use *que* in that case

- it allows avoiding to repeat *si*, which might not sound nice
- it denotes a cause/consequence relation between the two phrases

You could also use it with other forms, like *quand* for example

> Quand le feu est clignotant et qu'aucun véhicule n'arrive, tu peux traverser

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *si ... et que ...* has the same meaning as *si ... et si ...*.

> Si vous êtes pressé et si vous n'avez pas envie de prendre les transports en commun, vous pouvez toujours prendre un taxi.

But this form is heavier and a bit less natural.

Another example of conjunction that can be repeated with *que* is *comme*:

> Comme tu chantes bien et que tu as du temps, rejoins notre chorale !