# Is the second “que” necessary in “que […] et que […]”?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, subordonnées, coordination

I want to know whether the second “que” is absolutely necessary in a sentence like:

> Chaque fois que je me trouve dans un restaurant et **que** le café est cher, …
>   *Every time that I find myself in a restaurant and the coffee is expensive, …*

I first wrote it without the second “que”, but native proofreaders put it in for me. I don't see how it is necessary, because at least in my English brain, the logical structure feels like:

> Every time that ( [Condition A] and [Condition B] )

But if it is necessary, I guess I should see it more as:

> Chaque fois ( ( que [Condition A] ) et ( que [Condition B] ) )

Is the rule the same for any kind of “que” clause (with a different subject) joined by “et”?

- Je crois que Jean est gentil et **que** Marie est drôle
- Il me dit que Jean est gentil et **que** Marie est drôle

I'm not sure because in English, the second “that” is optional, and is often omitted. (In fact, even the first “that” is often omitted, but I know you can't do that in French.)

<sub>I found a [related question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6945/how-to-interpret-si-et-que-followed-by-a-main-clause), but it doesn't seem to address the necessity of the second “que”.</sub>

Comment: English brains often need to be turned off to better grasp the French language...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two “que” are necessary when the verbs are different:

> Je crois **que** Jean *est* gentil et **que** Marie *aime* danser.

If it is the same verb, you can put one (don’t repeat the verb) or two “que”:

> Je crois **que** Jean *est* gentil et Marie drôle.
>   Je crois **que** Jean *est* gentil et **que** Marie *est* drôle.

Answer (score 1):

"que < A >" and "que < B >" are components (*propositions subordonnées*) of the sentence that replace a noun used as direct object of the verb "croire".

In other words, the logic behind such construction is:

```
<sentence> = <subject> <verb> <direct_object1> and <direct_object2>.
```

where:

```
 <direct_object1> = que <A>
 <direct_object2> = que <B>
```